# My @media print doesn't display correctly with Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, printing

The print looks great on Chrome and Safari, but weird on Firefox. I couldn't find resources on how to fix @media print on Firefox? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Edit: The page breaks don't work for me on Firefox. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and on Firefox the text doesn't align in the same way as on e.g. Chrome.

Here is my CSS:

```
@media print {
   h1 {
      color: #000;
   }

   .navbar {
      display: none;
   }

   h1, h2, h3 {
  page-break-after: avoid;
   }    


a[href^=http]:after {
       content:" <" attr(href) "> ";
    }

a[href^="#"]:after {
       content: "";
}

   body {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: none;
   }

  @page {
     margin: 2cm;
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by weird? What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Sorry about that! I edited the description. I think the problem might be related to me using the responsive Bootstrap theme? For me, on Chrome the responsiveness works with printing, but not with Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Gecko doesn't support `page-break-after: avoid`.  Does that explain the behavior you see?